# How to Get List Database MySQL with PHP and MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql

How to Get List Database MySQL with PHP and MYSQLI ?

in mysql in can use query "SHOW DATABASE" because parameter in function mysql_connect MYSQL just SERVER, USER, PASSWORD but in MYSQLI function MYSQLI_CONNECT is SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SELECT table_name, table_type, engine
    -> FROM information_schema.tables
    -> ORDER BY table_name DESC;
```

Please connect to information_schema table

Answer (score 0):

Login, and do this cmd:
 show databases;